# create a scheduling method to display custom labels on 7 day rotation in Objective C (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making an app for my school. We are on a 7 day rotation schedule...so today is a G day, tomorrow will be an A day, Thursday B, Friday C, and Monday back to D. I want to put a UILabel on the homepage of my app that will output which "day" it is according to our schools A-G notation...can anyone think of a way to do this (that will be understood by a beginner)?

**the problem with that is that Monday is not always an "A" day, because we go on a 7 day cycle but only go to school 5 days a week. Any ways around this?**

I currently use NSDateFormatter hooked up to a string then to a UILabel to display the current day of the week, if that helps. code for that is below.

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

   //get the date today

   NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMMM dd"];

  NSString *dateToday = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

   [currentdate setText:dateToday];


   //get the time today

   NSDateFormatter *timeformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [timeformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

   NSString *timeToday = [timeformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
   [currenttime setText:timeToday];
```

**question:**

would I use "setText:" to output it to the label? I declared an outlet called *letterday in my .h, and now am trying to send the letter to it, and then this in my .m:

```
[NSDate JL_currentRotationDayWithSchoolYearBeginningOnDateString:@"2011-09-12"];

[letterday setText:
```

does that look right? sorry im so behind on this...

Comment: What happens to your schedule when there is a holiday or break? Does the rotation pause, or do those days count?

Comment: it pauses...so the last day before winter break would be a B day, and the first day back would be a C day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the source code for the entire category here with comments: https://gist.github.com/1590955

`#import "NSDate+RotationScheduleFormatter.h"` in every implementation file in which you would like to use the category. Then use the following method call to get the current rotation day:

`[NSDate JL_currentRotationDayWithSchoolYearBeginningOnDateString:@"2011-08-01"];` where the date is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

This will return a enum of type `RotationDay`, one of `kRotationDay[A-G]`.

In order for holiday breaks and other weekdays off of school to work you need to go into the .m file and edit the method called `+ (int)numberOfWeekdayBreakDaysBetweenSchoolYearBeginningDate:(NSDate *)beginningDate andEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate1`

In it you will see an array called `weekdayBreakArray` with a few values (in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`). Remove these test values and add in every day of every break that lands on a weekday. **Do not** add dates that are on weekends.

**Implementation:**

Assuming there exists a `UILabel` called `rotationLetter`, you can do the following:

```
RotationDay rotationDayInt = [NSDate JL_currentRotationDayWithSchoolYearBeginningOnDateString:@"2011-08-01"];
if (rotationDayInt == kRotationDayA) {
    [rotationLetter setText:@"A"];
}
else if (rotationDayInt == kRotationDayB) {
    [rotationLetter setText:@"B"];
}
```

and so on with more `else if` statements until you reach `kRotationDayG`.

**Notes:**

*Remember to enclose your call to this method in an if statement that checks if you're on a holiday break or on the weekend since the result will be incorrect otherwise. Also note that I did not optimize this class for memory management using manual retain/release because I wasn't sure if you're using ARC. **Furthermore, the entire system fails if you have a snow day or some other unexpected break and you cannot update the app in time. Therefore I highly advise that you download the array of dates from a server every time you open the app in case you need to make a change on the fly.***

Comment: i guess the problem with that is that Monday is not always an "A" day, because we go on a 7 day cycle but only go to school 5 days a week. Any ways around this?

Comment: Ok Thanks...what about a solution that creates a custom NSDate Format...one that just cycled through 7 different letters? I guess weekends would pose a problem with that though. Worst case, since I know in advance the rest of the days for the year I could just assign each day a different letter for the whole year...then I wouldn't have to update the code until next school year..? This way may work...

Comment: Updated with working code. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: thanks so much. When I get home in a few hours I will play around with it and let you know what happens.

Comment: I updated my original question with a question about your answer at the bottom...basically just how to implement it and call it to display the current day...beginner stuff I know. as far as the snow days, we totally skip over that day if its an unexpected missed day of school. Although I do get what your saying, and I will try to get it so I pull the array straight from a server. Thanks!

Comment: okay so `[NSDate JL_...]` returns an integer, so you need to make an if/else block that's like `if ([NSDate JL_...] == kRotationDayA) {[letterday setText:@"A"];} else if ([NSDate JL_...] == kRotationDayB) {[letterday setText:@"B"];}`

Comment: ah got it. Ok will try that now

Comment: for some reason the correct day is off...if you have any time could you take a quick look? it is here: https://gist.github.com/1591935 , and I also uploaded an excel sheet that says which calendar day is what letter day, for the whole academic year: http://cl.ly/2g1G0s112a470m2x3L0V

Comment: Thanks for the details. I updated my gist, see line 4 of the first file where I set kRotationDayA = 1. That's because enums (short for enumeration) start at 0 and go to 6 like an index, where as the days go from 1 to 7. I checked it against your excel doc and it seems to be working. One more note - in that long list of dates you've got for holiday breaks etc, you're missing a few commas between strings.

Comment: I added the =1 after kRotationDayA, but Something still seems wacky. I changed my computer's date to Sept. 12th to simulate the first day of school, and it is spitting out an "F" Day, and when i try the 13th it spits out an "E" day...almost as if its starting at F and moving backwards down the ladder, instead of restarting back at A after it gets to G. If you are spending too much time on this please let me know...I hate to keep coming back to you like this. I just feel back that you have helped me out so far. I am going to keep throwing in dates and see if an obvious error comes to me.

Comment: When I keep moving through the dates one problem I see is that after an A day I get an G day, so it seems like the trend is moving in the order of G, F, E, D, C, B, A, then back to G. I guess it should be the other way around, so after an A day is logically a B day, and so on. The starting the year on an F day seems like another problem, but I think they are two separate incidents.

Comment: Thanks for all the debugging, most people are just like "ahh it's not working fix it" :) I've got a CS lab to finish but I will take a look again after it's done tonight or tomorrow afternoon. This is fun stuff. Certainly much more complex than it seemed at first glance.

Comment: Ahah! check the gist again. Line 63 of the second file. I removed the `7 -` part, which was reversing it. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: no problem...thanks so much for working on it. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.

Comment: Hmm..somethings still a little screwy. I am testing it going day by day, and one week it will repeat D twice, one week it will handle D correctly, one week F twice, etc... But, the order does go correctly now. If you have time to look for any other problems that would be great, but if not you were a huge help getting me this far! I don't know anyone who could dissect this but maybe a second pair of eyes (of someone your technical skill set, not mine!) would help...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6596/discussion-between-jack-lawrence-and-fitz-tepper)